# How to show image within HTML table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display image within table cell using variable for a image src.
I show my text data as follows but I failed to display image on the table.

```
var div = document.getElementById('packsTable');

      $.each(childData, function(key, item) {
          ImageUrl = "Brush_Basic1.png";
          var typeName = childData[key];
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<td>'+key+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].ID+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].LOCK+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].LOCKED+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].PLAYSTORE+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].THUMBNAIL+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].TR+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+ImageUrl+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+attr("src", ImageUrl)+'</td></div>'; 
      })
```

How to show the image within table.

Comment: Where is the `attr` function defined? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am correct you are trying to display a image in your html table? Well then
you have to create a img html element `<img src="'+ImageUrl+'"></img>` so something like:

```
 $.each(childData, function(key, item) {
          ImageUrl = "Brush_Basic1.png";
          var typeName = childData[key];
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<td>'+key+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].ID+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].LOCK+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].LOCKED+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].PLAYSTORE+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].THUMBNAIL+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+childData[key].TR+'</td>'
                      + '<td>'+ImageUrl+'</td>'
                      + '<td><img src="'+ImageUrl+'"></img></td></div>'; 
      })
```